# For loop, can't assign function call - trying to create variables in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, assign

So I'm trying to recreate this:

```
    self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.user_frame, image = self.image1, state = 'disabled', command = self.press1)
    self.button1.pack(side = 'left')
    self.buttonList.append(self.button1)

    self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self.user_frame, image = self.image2, state = 'disabled', command = self.press2)
    self.button2.pack(side = 'left')
    self.buttonList.append(self.button2)

    self.button3 = tkinter.Button(self.user_frame, image = self.image3, state = 'disabled', command = self.press3)
    self.button3.pack(side = 'left')
    self.buttonList.append(self.button3)
```

etc.. up to self.button10.

With this:

```
for x in range [1, 11]:
        self.button(x)=tkinter.Button(self.user_frame, image=self.image(x), state = 'disabled', command = self.press(x))
        self.button(x).pack(side='left')
        self.buttonList.append(self.button(x))
```

I get syntaxerror: can't assign to function call. I know it has something to do with how I'm naming the buttons, but I can't figure it out. Any tips?

Comment: You may want to take a look at `setattr`, which will let you declare variables in the way you're talking about (I don't have any Tkinter experience so I'm not sure if there is a solution that is better suited to that environment).

Comment: Just use a list of button objects.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a plethora of syntax errors. It's not `range [1, 11]`, it's `range(1, 11)`.
You can't assign to `self.button(x)` - that tries to call a function `self.button` with argument `x`.

Why don't you just use a list of buttons? It would be much, much simpler.

In any event, use something like `self.__setattr__("button" + str(x), <the new button>)`